# how to change transform.Translate speed

Tags: unity-game-engine, translate

i want to vibrate fast the miFat object at y axis for 5 seconds and i am using the script below:

```c#
bool Up;
float timer;

void LateUpdate()
{                
    if(timer <= 5) 
    {    
        if(Up)
        {                 
            miFat.transform.Translate(0, 0.1f, 0);
            Up = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            miFat.transform.Translate(0, -0.1f, 0);
            Up = true;
        }
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

but i want faster vibration. If i change 0.1f to something else it changes the vibration velocity. How can i change the vibration speed?

Comment: This is not a proper way to shake an object. Try to randomize this. See `UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere` from the duplicate.

Comment: Can you maybe explain us what for you is the difference between `vibration velocity` and `vibration speed`? It now alters the direction with the frame rate .. what is supposed to happen if you make this faster? You wouldn't even see it anymore.

Comment: it is a vibrating guitar string. it must be vibrating at warp speed..  vibration velocity is how much distance up and down goes. vibration speed is how much fast up and down goes.